# a unrecognized domain vultrusercontent.com resolving to my localhost

Tags: dns

I just saw something interesting monitoring my fail2ban log I cannot really explain.  Well maybe losing my mind

My fail2ban registered this:

```
2022-04-06 14:26:09,703 fail2ban.filter         [1039]: INFO    [wordpress] Found 108.61.177.131 - 2022-04-06 14:26:08
2022-04-06 14:26:10,313 fail2ban.ipdns          [1039]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: 108.61.177.131.vultrusercontent.com = set(['127.0.0.1'])
2022-04-06 14:26:10,314 fail2ban.filter         [1039]: INFO    [wordpress] Ignore 127.0.0.1 by ignoreself rule
```

When I saw resolved localhost, then I saw fail2ban ignored filter on 127.0.0.1, I told myself weird, let me ping it for sh!ts and giggles.

```
[root@virtual ~]# ping vultrusercontent.com
PING vultrusercontent.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mydomain.ca (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from mydomain.caca (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms
```

Why is this resolving to my server?  I do not have this domain or anything..

Did this domain owner somehow created a record that points to me, and have it resolve to a 127.0.0.1?  This way fail2ban will ignore it, right?  Am I loosing it?  Can you even do that!?

```
[root@virtual ~]# dig vultrusercontent.com

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.9 <<>> vultrusercontent.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48929
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;vultrusercontent.com.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
vultrusercontent.com.   900 IN  A   127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 15 msec
;; SERVER: 67.207.67.2#53(67.207.67.2)
;; WHEN: Wed Apr 06 14:33:42 EDT 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65
```

Then I pinged from two other public machines with total different domains:

```
user@someotherbox:~$ ping vultrusercontent.com
PING vultrusercontent.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
^C
```

```
[me@debian ~]# ping vultrusercontent.com 
PING vultrusercontent.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.045 ms
^C
```

Am I missing something or having a blah moment?
My result show mxtoolbox dns lookup points to localhost as well

`https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3avultrusercontent.com&run=toolpage`

All these machines, do not use the same dns servers.  I usually do use 1.1.1.1

Comment: check your Hosts file, and your DNS server. do you use a PiHole or DNS RPZ zone or other blackholing service? the most common way to blackhole a domain name is to map it to 127.0.0.1. that way your systems cannot lookup that domain and contact it.

Comment: @FrankThomas you've jumped the gun here. Try pinging that domain yourself and you'll find out that the A record is actually poiinting to 127.0.0.1

Comment: fair enough. I was just asking the probing questions and suggesting things to check, as well as providing the rationale for why they were pertinent, but I hear ya.

Comment: Anybody can make their domain point at whatever IP address. That in itself is not hacking or anything. What you have here is a mismatch between forward DNS (_108.61.177.131.vultrusercontent.com._ points at _127.0.0.1_) and reverse DNS (_108.61.177.131_ points at _108.61.177.131.vultrusercontent.com._). Sounds like your fail2ban is configured a little strange.

Comment: @DanielB interesting, in my research I get an ip address from amsterdam, you get one from another country.

Comment: It’s just the IP address that started this all, in the first log line.

Comment: @DanielB ah, my bad... :)

Answer (score 2):

The domain is actually pointing to 127.0.0.1. Its most likely that the website in question got hacked and a script/bot is attempting to connect to your system.

In some cases the 127.0.0.1 can be normal. Usually this is the case for a domain that is not meant to be accessed from the outside. For example, you could setup a subdomain sql and point it to 127.0.0.1 such that you can use mysql.connect(sql.domain.ext;uname;pass;dbname) and it would work. For a top level domain, this is unusual unless you hack a website to do malicious stuff.

Comment: I hope it doesn't have a reverse lookup entry.

Comment: @FrankThomas Don't know. Can't seem to get much out of it, but this is actually a very interesting way to cloack a domain for malicous stuff. For example, if I who.is it, it tries to who.is itself. Kinda funny. Google does show history about the domain though, but can't make heads or tails of that either. So far my search comes to Vultr Holdings Llc Amsterdam, and they seem to be a cloud hosting provider, so the 127.0.0.1 may actually be intentional for this domain. (https://www.vultr.com)